# EKEventViewController wont show Edit Button on iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, ios13, xcode11, eventkit

i got a simple app where i want to present an event within an EKEventViewController.

```
    // the button action which validates if the event store access is granted and presents the given alert if true
    @IBAction func actionButtonShowPopover(_ sender: Any) {
        eventStore.requestAccess(to: .event) { (granted, _) in
            guard granted else { return }

            let event = self.generateAndSaveEvent()
            self.presentEventViewController(withEvent: event)
        }
    }
```

```
    // creates and tries to save an sample even and returns it
    private func generateAndSaveEvent() -> EKEvent {
        let event = EKEvent(eventStore: eventStore)

        event.title = "Event Title"
        event.startDate = Date()
        event.endDate = Date().addingTimeInterval(1800)
        event.calendar = eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents

        do {
            try eventStore.save(event, span: .thisEvent)
        } catch(let error) {
            print(error)
        }

        return event
    }
```

```
    // displays an EKEventViewController with our newly created event within an popover
    private func presentEventViewController(withEvent event: EKEvent) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let eventVC = EKEventViewController()

            eventVC.event = event
            eventVC.allowsEditing = true

            eventVC.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
            eventVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.buttonShowPopover
            eventVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = self.buttonShowPopover.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: -10)
            eventVC.popoverPresentationController?.backgroundColor = .white
            eventVC.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = .up

            self.present(eventVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

i created an event as shown in the code above and simply displaying it within the popover view controller. since ios 13 i got a different result:

[iOS 12.4 with edit button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0OFx.png)

[iOS 13 without edit button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osAud.png)

is there any chance i'm missing changes from iOS12 -> iOS13? 
thanks upfront - i'm grateful for any advice!

Comment: I'm having trouble where after presenting the EKEventEditViewController the add button is there but not tappable for some reason.  I pre-create an EKEvent for it.

Comment: What do you mean by "not tappable"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit button has moved to navigation bar in iOS 13. You need to present it without popover style.

Comment: Navigation Controller [Presented as Popover] + EKEventViewController [embedded as a ChildVC] works! Thank you! :-)

Answer (score 1):

In my app, that's been around for a while, I was experiencing the same problem with the edit button no longer appearing in iOS13. Unlike other users, my `EKEventViewController` was already wrapped in a navigation controller, so it wasn't that issue.

Several hours of going down rabbit holes, I've found a fix. Here's where the problems were occurring in my app:

- Debugging just before opening the view, the `EKEvent` object I was trying to edit didn't have a value set for `.eventIdentifier`. Reading into this, it seems this property is lazy loaded, so not being able to retrieve the value here suggests the link between the `EKEvent` and the `EKStore` I used to fetch it has been lost somewhere in the application lifecycle. This is a change that been introduced somewhere along the iOS/Swift upgrade journey - I can't pin down the change that has caused this.
- By accessing the `EKEvent.eventIdentifier` at the time I first retrieved the `EKEvent`, I now had this identifier for later use
- Before presenting the EKEventViewController, I fetch a fresh copy of this event and use the fresh event in the controller:

```
let freshEvent = store.event(withIdentifier: staleEvent.eventIdentifier) 
eventViewController.event = freshEvent
```